# Chocolatey says "Software installed to 'C:\Program Files\Chromium\Application" but nothing is there

Tags: chromium, chocolatey

I'm trying to install Chromium with Chocolatey: `choco install -y chromium`

I get the following output:

```
Installing the following packages:
chromium
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading chromium 104.0.5112.102... 100%

chromium v104.0.5112.102 [Approved]
chromium package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
Chromium 104.0.5112.102 is already installed.
Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed. Close/reopen your shell to
 see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`).
 The install of chromium was successful.
  Software installed to 'C:\Program Files\Chromium\Application'

Chocolatey installed 1/1 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
```

However, no folder is created for the Chromium application in `C:\Program Files`. I *am* getting a new installation of the NuGet for Chromium in `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\chromium`.

I'm doing this as part of an attempt to automate a Chromium installation, so I've been messing around with lots of different chromium versions and force installs. The line `Chromium 104.0.5112.102 is already installed.` looks pretty suspect, as does [the note in the Chocolatey chromium page](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/chromium/104.0.5112.102#description) that says that sometimes the package will be installed on `%localappdata%\Chromium` instead, but I can't find chromium installed in `C:\Users\jkatofsky\AppData\Local` either.

I feel like the issue is just within reach, but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `choco uninstall -n --skipautouninstaller chromium` *and* going to `Control Panel -> Programs -> Uninstall a program` then uninstalling Chromium, and getting rid of it from the registry when prompted, fixed things for me. The next `choco install chromium` worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The package is already installed (note I said package) so it won't be installed again. I think messing around with versions has caused that issue.

Uninstall the package and install it again.

Comment: `choco uninstall` fails, because it can't find the chromium binary: `Uninstalling Chromium...
WARNING: May not be able to find 'C:\Program Files\Chromium\Application\104.0.5112.102\Installer\setup.exe'. Please use full path for executables.
ERROR: Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified"
chromium uninstall not successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\chromium\tools\chocolateyUninstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
chromium not uninstalled. An error occurred during uninstall:
 chromium uninstall not successful.`

Comment: And manually deleting `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\chromium` and reinstalling does not change anything :(